# ExpressJS Post Method - No Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, cors

I have been reading all the articles that I found about CORS but I'm still not able to solve this issue - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

I need to make a **post request** to my node/expressjs server using jquery ajax but I can't get it working.

This is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://mydevserver:3000/api/nnnn',
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("success!");
    }
});
```

And this the expressJS part where I set the response headers:

```
var corsOrigin  ;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
   console.log('Adding CORS to the headers...');
   corsOrigin = 'myprodserver';
}
else {
  corsOrigin = 'http://mydevserver:4200';
}


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", corsOrigin);
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');

  next();

});
```

What am I missing here? I ran out of options...

Thanks very much for the help!

My best regards.

**Update 1 - Full server and route codes**

server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var app = require('./app');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

console.log('Server port set to ' + process.env.NODE_PORT);
var port = normalizePort(process.env.NODE_PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);

    if (isNaN(port)) {
        // named pipe
        return val;
    }

    if (port >= 0) {
        // port number
        return port;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
        throw error;
    }

    var bind = typeof port === 'string'
        ? 'Pipe ' + port
        : 'Port ' + port;

    // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
    switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
            console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
            console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            throw error;
    }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
    var addr = server.address();
    var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
        ? 'pipe ' + addr
        : 'port ' + addr.port;
    console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var fs = require('fs');

var cors = require("cors");

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: 150000000, extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));

var corsOrigin  ;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
   console.log('Adding CORS to the headers...');
   corsOrigin = 'prodserver';
}
else {
  corsOrigin = 'http://localhost:4200';
}


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', corsOrigin);
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE");
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    next();
});



var globSync          = require('glob').sync;
var routes            = globSync('./routes/*.js', { cwd: __dirname}).map(require);


AWS.config.update({
  region: "xxxx",
  accessKeyId: "xxxx",
  secretAccessKey: "xxxxxxx"
});

var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

routes.forEach( function(route) { 
    route(app, ddb);
});

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.use('/api/resources', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'resources')));


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: I would suggest using this module. https://github.com/expressjs/cors It will set everything for you.

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk I'd tried that one also. No lucky either. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You sure you try it right? like app.use(cors(corsOptions)); Where corsOptions you can get from cors wiki. Because i use the same module in production and never have any issues. But no problem. Hope you will find your answer.

Comment: Btw...Can you post code for all expressJs part and node server ?

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk just updated the question with the full code.

Comment: Please use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46606599/edit to edit/update the question and paste in the exact error message you’re seeing in your browser devtools console. Also Please go into your Network pane in your browser devtools and reload and copy the details of the response that doesn’t have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin — including the response status code — and also the details of the request that response is for.

Comment: Your frontend JavaScript code adds `contentType: "application/json"` to the request, that triggers your browser to automatically on its own do a CORS preflight OPTIONS request before trying the POST request from your code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests. So unless your server is configured to handle OPTIONS requests correctly, then the request that’s causing the response you’re getting is actually that preflight OPTIONS request from the browser, and the solution it to update your server code to handle preflight OPTIONS requests.

Comment: Remember to configure cors etc before setting up any routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by sideshowbarker, I was passing the contentType: "application/json" in my ajax call. That was the problem. The following is the working code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://mydevserver:3000/api/nnnn',
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    async: true,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("success!");
    }
});
```

Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Try like this in express node :

```
var origin = "http://localhost:4200";
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin || "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-Type,x-requested-with');
    next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I still getting the same issue: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Comment: try this res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); instead of specific origin

Comment: Same result, Chandru.

Comment: @Marrone try the above but add `app.options('*', cors())` before the `app.use(function(req, res, next) {` line. That enables support for CORS preflight OPTIONS requests.

Comment: @sideshowbarker still getting the same issue: Failed to load http://localhost:3000/api/xxxx: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.